# How to spatial partition a spatialRDD with GeoSpark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, geospatial, rdd

Is there a way to spatial partition a spatialRDD in GeoSpark effectively?
e.g: partitions with many points close to each other to be in 1 partition using GeoSpark or something simmilar?

Answer (score 4):

As an extension to Georg comment, I'd like to show you an example of using QuadTree. Haven't used the rest of partition methods, but I expect them to behave the same (except of the actual partitioning, of course). Provided that the variable you want to partition is `pointsRDD` (which is actually an object of type PointRDD in my case), you can do it the following way:

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.index.quadtree.Quadtree
import com.vividsolutions.jts.index.SpatialIndex

val buildOnSpatialPartitionedRDD = true // Set to TRUE only if run join query
val numPartitions = 48
pointsRDD.analyze()
pointsRDD.spatialPartitioning(GridType.QUADTREE, numPartitions)
pointsRDD.buildIndex(IndexType.QUADTREE, buildOnSpatialPartitionedRDD)
```

You'll find the partitioned data in `pointsRDD.spatialPartitionedRDD.rdd`:

```
pointsRDD
  .spatialPartitionedRDD
  .rdd
  .mapPartitions(yourFunctionYouWantToRunOnEachPartition)
```

You can inspect the partitions by referring to the partition tree:

```
pointsRDD.partitionTree.getAllZones.asScala.foreach(println)
```

which will yield something like

```
x: 15.857028 y: 53.36364 w: 9.872338000000003 h: 2.7383549999999985 PartitionId: null Lineage: null
x: 15.857028 y: 54.732817499999996 w: 4.936169000000001 h: 1.3691774999999993 PartitionId: null Lineage: null
x: 15.857028 y: 55.41740625 w: 2.4680845000000007 h: 0.6845887499999996 PartitionId: null Lineage: null
x: 15.857028 y: 55.759700625 w: 1.2340422500000003 h: 0.3422943749999998 PartitionId: null Lineage: null
x: 15.857028 y: 55.9308478125 w: 0.6170211250000002 h: 0.1711471874999999 PartitionId: 0 Lineage: null
...
```

This can be visualised with your favourite plotting tool (can't include code for this, sorry):

[image: QuadNodes]

To check partition statistics, use the following code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
pointsRDD
  .spatialPartitionedRDD
  .rdd
  .mapPartitionsWithIndex{case (i,rows) => Iterator((i,rows.size))}
  .toDF("partition_number","number_of_records")
  .show()
```

which will give you:

```
+----------------+-----------------+
|partition_number|number_of_records|
+----------------+-----------------+
|               0|             8240|
|               1|             7472|
|               2|             5837|
|               3|             3753|
+----------------+-----------------+
only showing top 4 rows
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://datasystemslab.github.io/GeoSpark/tutorial/rdd/#use-spatial-partitioning

- KDB-Tree
- Quad-Tree
- R-Tree

are implemented